# Shell is selecting Python 2.7, but not 3.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, python-2.7

I have `Python 3.7` and I had a `Python 2.7.`

But when I am using Python Launcher it uses 2.7 not 3.7.

How to use `Python 3.7`? OS - Mac OS.

Comment: Type `python37` instead of just `python` when launching python from the terminal. If you're opening the app "Python Launcher", there should be two separate python launchers, use the 3.7 one.

Comment: If you installed Python 3.7 via **homebrew**, re-read `brew info python` and set your PATH how it advises.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want python 3.7 as default when you run command **python** in terminal, you can add an alias in ~/.bashrc

```
alias python=python3.7
```

bashrc is a shell script that bash runs whenever it is started interactively. You can find bashrc in your home directory.

Answer (score 0):

In the Python Launcher menu, go to Preferences.  You should see a text box called "Interpreter", in there insert the path to your python 3.7,  for example:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3
```

You might also add that to your `PATH` environment variable and use `python3` (and `idle3`) rather than plain `python`.

Answer (score -1):

There are several ways you can obtain this behavior, my preferred one is symlinking the python3 executable to python

```
sudo unlink /usr/bin/python
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python
```

Another way would be using pyenv https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv

Be aware od the fact that if you do this and you have some scripts on your machine that use the shebang #! /bin/python and were written for py2, they may stop working

Comment: Do not do this - EVER! It's a really, really BAD IDEA to alter binaries in the system directories - it could cause all sorts of havoc. That's what *local* directories and PATHs are for.

Comment: I'm not objecting what you say but that is only one piece of the story. You are omitting the fact that python itself create a /usr/bin/python executable, the first version you install will leave you with the executable. If you don't use py2 at all but you only have some packages depending on it you can switch with no problem. Not all OS come out with python. OS should be made by you, not for you. I explained the downside of doing this so I really don't get the down vote.